# Display Drupal taxonomy tree

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I sucessfully printed the whole taxonomy tree using this code.

```
$voc = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('product_sub_categories');
$tree = taxonomy_get_tree($voc->vid, 0, NULL, TRUE);
foreach ($tree as $key => $term) {
  print $term->name."</br>";
}
```

Now I want to separately print parent and child in order to custom theme them, because I already have a mark-up in which parent has separate  `<p class="parent_class"> Parent terms</p>` and children has separate `<ul class="child_class">Child terms</ul>`.

How should I do this?

---

I have done it using `taxonomy_get_children()`, but it is giving me the children of parent of the taxonomy whose ID is 1.

- child1
- child2
- child3

This is what I need, but now I want to get the children of parent 
`child1`. I tried to get them by reusing the above function but it give me this.

- child1

  - children of child1
- child1
- child2
- child3

Answer (score 2):

Use nested foreach like below.

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_children(1);
foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $items[] = $term->name;
  $child_term = taxonomy_get_children($term->tid);
  if (!empty($child_term)) {
    foreach ($child_term as $child) {
      $items[] = $child->name;
    }

  }
}
return theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
```

Comment: thanku @ganesan for your reply, but it gave me error for line `$items[] = $term->name;`

Comment: @nomeer I think you have used $items variable as object somewhere for some other purpose. Please check that and you could rename the variable name.